# Generate a performance/bandwidth graph between X and Y algorithms in Cooja Contiki

Tags: performance-testing, contiki, cooja

**Approach:** 
I would like to Generate a performance/bandwidth graph between X and Y algorithms in Cooja Contiki Simulator. I will run both algorithms on the server by assuming Node A will run the X algorithm on Dataset-A and Node B will use the Dataset-B for Y Algorithm. Is it possible to capture the performance graph while running both algorithms?

I am not much familiar with the cooja simulator that is why I need help with this.

Your responses will be appreciated.

Thanks